# Block inside another block

Tags: 7, blocks, javascript

I'm using *jquery countdown timer*, I want to but it in the *main page content block*. How do I put a block inside another block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the url `/admin/structure/block` you can set Blocks to Regions on your site.
You simply drag and drop the block(s) to the given Region of your page and `Save` the block ordering on that page. In this screenshot I have 3 blocks in the main content area for my theme:

[image]

You can then go into each block with the `configure` link and set that block to show only on certain page(s) for instance, or only for certain Roles of the site.

This is the simplest means using Core drupal and no 3rd party modules.

If you want to eventually look into other means of doing this look into the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module, or [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

Comment: As new I am to drupal this much I know. I want to put i.e. View: css_slideshow block "into" Main page content block (not above or below)

Comment: it is *in* main page content block, it happens to be the 1st block placed therein. If you want it say, inside the Node content ... thats not a block within a block :P that's a block within the node content. You could create a module and use [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) along with [views_embed_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21views.module/function/views_embed_view/7), or for a [block](http://drupal.org/node/1032068#comment-3971438) into the node.